# How to display error on the page after service return an error to the controller in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

Now I have tried to display the response which is returned from the service to the controller..When I am trying to display the error its not working.The below is the code which i have tried

```
var app=angular.module('httpExample',[]);
app.controller("FetchController",["$scope","clickevent",function($scope,clickevent){
    clickevent.fetch().then(function(response){
        $scope.req=response;
        console.log(angular.toJson(response));
    }).error(function(error){
          console.log(error);
     });

}]);
app.service("clickevent",['$http',function($http){

        var clickevent={
                fetch:function(){
                    var prom=$http({method:"GET",url:"http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php"}).
                    success(function(response){
                        return response;
                    }).
                    error(function(err){
                        return err;
                    });
                    return prom;
                }
        };
        return clickevent;
    }]);
```

Comment: You have misspelled `function` in line `}).error(fucntion(error){` (line 6)

Comment: Ohk sorry..Even though its not giving any error

Comment: in `clickevent.fetch` return the promise?

Answer (score 0):

Promises don't have an `error()` function. They have a `catch()` function. `success()` and `error()` are specific to promises returned by $http, and those **deprecated** functions don't allow chaining like `then()` and `catch()` allow.

Here's how your code should look like:

```
var app = angular.module('httpExample',[]);

app.controller("FetchController",["$scope", "clickevent", function($scope, clickevent){
    clickevent.fetch().then(function(data) {
        $scope.req = data;
        console.log(angular.toJson(data));
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}]);

app.service("clickevent",['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    var clickevent = {
        fetch: function() {
            var prom = $http({method:"GET",url:"http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php"}).
                then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                }).
                catch(function(response) {
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                });
            return prom;
        }
    };
    return clickevent;
}]);
```

Comment: even if iam using it ,the response is only displayed even though there is an error

Comment: Well, that code displays the body of the response when the response is an error response. What do you want to display instead?

Comment: I am changing the method to POST to check whether error occurs or not...So what an error occures when the method is changed ,that error must be displayed on the page.Is it possible

Comment: What exactly do you want to display? Give a concrete example, with a concrete response returned by the server and a concrete error message to display.

Comment: I am unable to express...I can say you that ,here which i have posted the code displays an response.data..If an  error occurs,it may be server or other ,that error must be displayed.

Comment: If you don't know what must be displayed, I don't seehow I could tell you to display it.